# Validate Json schema C#

Tags: c#, json, validation, jsonschema, jsonparser

I'm trying to validate my json file but my validation doesn't work properly. Please help me to understand what is wrong.

```
 public static bool ValidJson(string jasonData)
        {
            string myJson = @"{
            'description': 'rehber',
            'type': 'object',
            'properties':
            {
               'isim': {'type':'string', 'required': true },
               'tel': {'type':'string','required': true},
            },
            'additionalProperties': false
         }";

            JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(myJson);

            JToken rehber = JToken.Parse(jasonData);
            bool valid = rehber.IsValid(schema);
            return valid;
        }
```

jasonData that comes to ValidJson function is like that:

```
 "[\n  {\n    \"isim\": \"Ahmet\",\n    \"tel\": \"+46 637 530 68 94\"\n  },\n  {\n    \"isim\": \"Mahmet\",\n    \"tel\": \"+46 637 530 68 91\"\n  }\n]"
```

I changed my schema but it shows true all the time. I don't want additional fields in my json file and null values. But this schema doesn't work properly either.

```
string myJson = @"{
            'type': 'array',
            'title': 'The root schema',
            'description': 'The root schema comprises the entire JSON document.',
            'additionalItems': false,
            'items': {
                'allOf': [
                    {
                    'type': 'object',
                    'title': 'The first anyOf schema',
                    'description': 'An explanation about the purpose of this instance.',
                    'required': [   
                        'isim',
                        'tel'
                            ],
                'additionalProperties': false,
                'properties': {
                        'isim': {
                            'type': 'string',
                            },
                        'tel': {
                            'type': 'string',

                            }
                     }
                    }
                 ],
            }
        }";
```

Comment: We need more than "*doesn't work*". Can you give details?

Comment: You double quotes instead of single quotes in json

Comment: Your schema fits a single object while your input json contains an array of objects....

Comment: It shows false with these data. Also double quote shows an error everywhere. When I remove 'description': 'rehber',  'type': 'object',      it returns true

Comment: `"required": true` is not correct - `required` belongs at the object level and contains a list of properties, not a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you cannot pass the validation test is because your json data is actually an array, but not an single object.

If you assume your input data is an array, you may modify the code like:

```
        public static bool ValidJson(string jsonData)
        {
            string myJson = @"{
            'description': 'rehber',
            'type': 'object',
            'properties':
            {
               'isim': {'type':'string', 'required': true },
               'tel': {'type':'string','required': true},
            },
            'additionalProperties': false
         }";

            JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(myJson);
            JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonData);
            
            foreach( var jToken in jArray)
            {
                if ( !jToken.IsValid(schema))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;                        
        }
```

Please also noted that the JsonSchema & isValid method are deprecated, Newtonsoft has a new project, please check  https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema .